# Eclipse is not detecting my device

Tags: android, adb

I have updated my system from **Windows 8 32 bit to 64 bit**.Now my eclipse is not detecting the my device that **karbon A27+** .I have tried every thing and searched on stack overflow but nothing helped me .When i am running this command **adb devices** It is not showing my device.What could be the problem .

I have tried this

If you on Windows 8, you may have to Disable Driver Signing before that:

Move your mouse pointer to the upper right-hand side of your monitor. This will open the charm bar.
Click the Settings charm.
Click the Change PC settings link at the bottom of the Settings menu.

On the devices option it is showing that **no driver available on the Karbon A27+**

Comment: You should restart eclipse!

Comment: i have done that already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install 64-Bit USB drivers of your phone or try out with [this URL](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=36523572).

Check URL for detailed description.

[- Driver Link](https://dl-ssl.google.com//android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip)

[- Karbonn Smart A27+ PC Suite and USB Driver](http://www.downloads.techdiscussion.in/smartphones/karbonn-smart-a27-pc-suite-and-usb-driver/)